# Do Mafia lawyers exist?

Tags: united-states, lawyer

Do mob lawyers still exist? Can someone just call them and hire them for whatever job?

I mean... What if I end up in a serious situation and want the best lawyer (or assemble the lawyer army) for it? Logically such people must be the top notch people. After all they worked for the hardest most serious cases in the US.

Comment: "Better Call Saul"

Comment: I don't quite understand this question.  There are certainly lawyers who have defended or otherwise represented people associated with the Mafia.  Why would you think there are no longer any such people?

Comment: Question answered roughly. What I want to know is I'd like to know if there are active famous lawyers that are known for still serving mafia and if they would serve me (And how much they would charge) and if they are really the best defenders on earth

Comment: I agree that it isn't a simple question. For example, is a drug cartel a "mafia", what about the operators of a Ponzi scheme? There are definitely lawyers who specialize in defending people against the quintessential organized crime charge (RICO).

Comment: "if they would serve me" - no, unless you're also in the mafia. "how much they would charge" - more than you can afford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certianly people have been accused of Mafia-related crime, and have been defended by lawyers. If there are lawyers who make representing Mafia-related people a sizable part of their business (and I suspect that there are), they do not advertise this fact. So it is hard to know who such lawyers might be.

Such lawyers, if they exist, probably have specialized expertise in the problems and needs of such clients.  But that might not be particularly helpful to a non-Mafia person who needs a lawyer.

Comment: There may not be lawyers that only focus ont he mob, since its not the 40s anymore JK, but there are definitely lawyers who will lie for you.

Comment: @Putvi that is a very different question: "Ask a friend how much 2+2 is, without hesitation he'll tell you "it's four"; Ask an accountant, he'll say "I'm fairly certain, but let me run thru the figures once more"; a doctor will think about malpractice and tell you he's pretty sure at least it must be 3; A lawyer locks the doors and shuts the curtain, and whispers to you "how much do you want it to be". (From "The Cheap Lawyer")

Comment: Yeah, I get you, I just meant I think most people would consider the term mafia lawyer to be someone who will do something shady, not just one who only works for the mafia.

Comment: @Putvi Perhaps I've read too many mafia-focused thrillers, but to me it means specifically one who works for organized crime. Shady lawyers who work for unorganized criminals, or just have low ethics, I would not use that term for. Perhaps I'm unusual there.

Comment: I'm with you, I'm sure the mafia did use lawyers they knew were shady, but I mean what would be the point of picking a certain one if they picked a non shady one? There just are only so many mafia cases though.

Comment: "If there are lawyers who make representing Mafia-related people a sizable part of their business (and I suspect that there are), they do not advertise this fact." I suspect that they do advertise, but mostly via word of mouth (which is actually how most lawyers advertise most of the time). Until quite recently formal advertising by lawyers was heavily regulated and banned outside the most milquitoast recitals of name and constant information and maybe photo. Even trade names weren't even allowed until quite recently and are still rare.

Comment: "they do not advertise this fact"... just search RICO/racketeering defense attorney.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Cosa Nostra doesn't have an accreditation for lawyers. They have various organizational ranks, but none of these are related to the law.

Also, in Italy at least, they usually go extra-judicial when sorting out judicial issues, like bribing judges, threatening prosecutors and their families etc., which tends to be more effective that going through the legal process.